Neural network to approximate the square function gives 0 output
I'm trying to build a neural network to approximate the squares of numbers from -50 to 50. I've referred to the code in this answer to write mine:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

x_train = np.random.random((10000,1))*100-50
y_train = np.square(x_train)

model = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(8, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape = (1,)),
            Dense(8, activation = 'relu',  kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            Dense(1, activation = 'relu')
            ]

        )

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)

x = "n" 
while True:
    print("enter num:")
    x = input()
    if x == "end":
        break

    X = int(x)

    predicted_sum = model.predict(np.array([X]))
    print(predicted_sum)

The problem is, all inputs give rise to the output "[[0.]]". I don't know why this is caused and how to fix it, can someone help?
This message is displayed immediately after the code is executed, does it have something to do with the problem?
oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly
different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off
, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.


I get reasonable results by changing the batch size from 32 -> 256, changing the number of epochs from 100 to 1000, and removing the activation function from the last layer.

You should never have relu in the output layer because it cuts off gradients for outputs < 0, preventing the model from learning from those outputs.

@xdurch0 but the function we're trying to approximate is the square function, for which that isn't an issue, so why is relu causing problems? (I just tried changing only the activation to default  among the corrections nick suggested and it's now giving me wildly inaccurate, but at least non-zero answers)

@NickODell: Removing the activation function did the trick, although I ended up using a different batch size and number of epochs. Can you tell me why the relu was causing problems, as it's a square function and no output would ever be less than zero?

@NickODell: would you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

A randomly initialized network implements a random function. Most likely some outputs will be negative. These will be cut off to 0 by relu, with no gradient, meaning the network can never learn to "correct" these outputs. It doesn't matter what your target function is. With a particularly unlucky initialization, it could be that all outputs are negative pre-relu, in which case the network will never receive any gradient, so no learning and all-0 outputs.

BTW the same can happen for hidden units, where you can have "dead" units that never activate and are essentially useless. For this reason, I would advise against using relu at all in such a small network, as even one dead unit can have a big impact.

I get reasonable results by changing the batch size from 32 to 256, changing the number of epochs from 100 to 1000, and removing the ReLU activation function from the last layer.
ReLU has the problem that if the input to the activation is x < 0, then ReLU'(x) = 0. This means that if the output from the final layer happens to be negative, there will be no gradient to correct this.
This is also a problem in previous layers, but it is much more likely that a single neuron gets unlucky in this fashion than it is that eight neurons get unlucky.
As an alternative to removing it, you could also look into leaky ReLU.
Given that the original code trains this for 15,000 epochs, it is not very surprising that 100 epochs gets much worse results. I also changed the batch size to 256 with the intention of making the code run faster.

Good answer, thanks. But why would this ever be a problem? The output from the final layer would always be positive anyway, since we're dealing with a square function, right?

Not necessarily. Imagine that in some batch, all of the network's guesses are too high. It tries to fix that by changing the bias term to subtract from all future guesses. However, for some input which is not in the batch, this causes the output to be less than zero. If it gets into this state, then negative outputs will never result in a gradient to correct them.
